# Изменение содержимого текстового файла

Tags: text, файлы, c#

Есть txt файлы. К примеру, путь одного из них C:\Users\user\Desktop\1.txt,
содержимое txt файла: 2014-08-23 07:31:14 + текст (не важно какой).
Мне надо прибавить к этой дате + 14 дней и результат (датой) в textbox или в listbox.
Так как файлов много и следовательно дат, надо упорядочить по времени. 
Как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: @san81232 переформулируйте, пожалуйста, заголовок вопроса, а также более конкретно опишите суть вопроса. Пока что непонятно, что именно Вы хотите сделать с данными и о каких ListBox идет речь.

Comment: 1. Считайте текстовый файл.
2. Найдите в нём искомую дату, спарсьте её в переменную типа `DateTime`.
3. Прибавьте к этой дате две недели.
4. Результат выведите в textbox или listbox.

Какой из пунктов вызывает сложности? Что Вы пытались сделать и что не получилось?